# How to run sql query recursively?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, there is a accounts table has:

```
account_id | ......    
000        | ......    
001        | ......    
004        | ......    
010        | ......   
.....   
198        | ......
```

I want to get the distribution of account id, instead of running following query again and again, is there any smarter way to get id count for 000-010, 010-020, ..., 190-200? Thanks

```
SELECT count(account_id)
FROM accounts
WHERE account_id >= '000' AND  account_id <= '010';
```

Comment: You mean iteratively.  Although I'm suspicious of trying to segment ids this way, because (if they're auto-gen), the values are meaningless, and you should be using some natural key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the `account_id` by 10 to create a range and then group by the divided result to get the result you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LPAD(FLOOR(account_id/10)*10,3, '0'), '-', LPAD(FLOOR(account_id/10)*10+9, 3, '0')) AS `range`,
       COUNT(*) AS number
FROM accounts
GROUP BY `range`
```

Output (for some sample data in my demo):

```
range       number
000-009     3
010-019     2
020-029     1
030-039     1
040-049     1
050-059     2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b259de2f924442e50a15f4a38a28c5d3)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Note that this will omit empty buckets, so just be aware of that when processing the result

Answer (score 1):

You would use `group by`:

```
select (case when account_id >= '000' and account_id <= '010' then '000-010'
             when account_id >= '011' and account_id <= '020' then '011-020'
             when account_id >= '021' and account_id <= '030' then '021-030'
             . . .
        end) as account_id_grp,
       count(*)
from accounts
group by account_id_grp
order by account_id_grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     select t1.account_id ||'-'||t2.
     account_id,count(*) from 
     table t1 where account_id IN (Select account_id from 
      table t2 where t2.account_id-t1.account_id=10)`
```

> I tried like taking difference of the account ids in the tables via corelated subquery